# MATLAB - save image in structure array array{i,y} and retrieve with (image(i,y))?

Tags: arrays, image, multidimensional-array, imread

*My system:*

Windows 8.1
MATLAB2015a

My issue: When I save a JPG image in a structure array, in this case **stiAll{i,y}**

```
fileName = strcat('group_',strGr,'_',strVal,'.jpg');
fileNameStr = char(fileName);
stiAll{i,y} = imread(fileNameStr);
```

and I try to retrieve the saved image with **image(stiAll(i,y))** I get the following error message from MATLAB:

*Invalid datatype for Image CData. Numeric or logical
matrix required for image CData.*

If I save the image without the {i,y} suffix, so that the image is saved in a normal variable, not in a structure array, I can retrieve the image. However, for my programme I would need to save images in the respective cells of a structure array or something similar.

Any idea how to get this done successfully?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stiAll{i,y} = imread(fileNameStr);` looks like a cellArray.  And you try to plot it  `image(stiAll(i,y))`  now as Matrix.  Try `image(stiAll{i,y})`

Comment: Thanks jdl, that solved it. I need to use curly brackets not parentheses.